Find the generating function $\mathcal{B} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i+j+k=n}a_{i+j}a_{j+k}a_{k+i}\right)X^n.$
Consider a sequence $\{a_n\}$, the ordinary generating function for it is given by $\mathcal{A} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nX^n$. Then
$$\mathcal{A}^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i+j=n}a_i a_j\right)X^n$$
$$\mathcal{A}^3 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i+j+k=n}a_i a_j a_k\right)X^n$$
I encountered a problem that requires finding a generating function related to $\mathcal{A}$. Specifically, it is
$$\mathcal{B} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i+j+k=n}a_{i+j}a_{j+k}a_{k+i}\right)X^n.$$
I haven't figured out how it relates to $\mathcal{A}$.
